# To find string from entire directories and sub-directory files using grep/find

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, find

I have some list of directories and sub-directories, where i am trying search string from all the list of directories and sub-directories.

I am using the below command to do it. But it stops when it finds results in first search file. where I am expecting search to be performed on all files. please help me in forming the command.

```
find dir/ -type f -exec grep -H 'missippi' {} +
```

For eg: -

consider I have 15 files and I have string called "missippi" in 10 files. The search should be performed all 15 files and resulting 10 filenames should be displayed.

Comment: Did you search for `string` or `missippi`? The command you tried should work. `grep -r 'missippi' dir` should work too, since you seem to have `GNU grep`

Comment: @Sundeep i did search for 'missippi'

Comment: @Amith then please [edit] your question to show that.

Comment: There is nothing in the command you're running that would cause it to stop after reading the first file. Maybe its just taking longer than you expected to find all the files or maybe the files just don't exist under the directory you're looking in or maybe the rest of the files have `missippippi` spelled correctly and so they don't match `missippi`.

Comment: @EdMorton that is not true the word exists in 10 files are "missippi".. i tried executing command ```find dir/ -type f -exec grep -H 'missippi' {} +```

Comment: OK, well your command is correct, the problem is something else but we can't tell you what else as all we can see in your question is your command so all we can do is make suggestions of things you could consider. Are you getting any error messages? What value does `echo "$?"` produce as soon as the command completes?

Comment: Take `find` out of the equation - what is the output of `grep -H 'missippi' dir/foo/file1 dir/bar/file2` where those are both paths to files under `dir/` that you know contain `missippi`?

Comment: @EdMorton it displayed all the results contained in ```dir/foo/file1  dir/bar/file2```

Comment: @EdMorton i got my mistake i was reading the search string in command line argument .. where my $1 is the path need to be searched and $2 is the sting to be searched from command ```find $1 -type f -exec grep -H '$2' {} +``` where $2 was in single quoted that's the reason not getting expected result

Comment: That wouldn't explain the symptoms you described where `missippi` was being found in one of the files but not the others.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command:

```
 grep -nr 'string'
```

As you can see `grep` itself can search recursively. The `n` flag prints the line number of the occurrence in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find dir/ -type f | xargs grep 'missippi'
```